# How can I comment special \ commands in PostgreSQL's psql commandline tool?

Tags: postgresql, comments, psql

What's the character for comments for special commands that start with `\` in `psql`?

The following appears to work:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table     -- this is my comment
```

But this does not work:

```
\dt jvcurve_thin.jvcurve_results    --  my comment #2
```

\dt: extra argument "--" ignored

Comment: `psql` doesn't support trailing-line comments on its slash commands. Just put the comment on the line before.

Comment: The above response should be posted as an answer, not a comment. This will allow voting and follow-up comments. In particular, I recommend referring to [cjerdonek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20770978/109618).

Answer (score 77):

According to [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-COMMENTS), there are both the inline and the block style comments.

The **inline** style:

```
SELECT 23 AS test  -- this is just a test
```

The **block** style:

```
/* The following is a very
 * non-trivial SQL code */
SELECT 42 AS result
```

Comment: He asks how to comment in psql interactive console scripts (i.e. include commenting its backslashed meta-commands, which is the trick), not how comment the regular Postgres SQL.

Comment: @PetrPivonka The title of this question "Comment character/characters in postgres / postgresql / psql?" is how the search engines primarily index it.

Answer (score 22):

In SQL comment starts with `--`.

Comment: C-style comments are also allowed by most databases but I'm not sure which (if any) SQL standard stipulates them: `/* comment */`

Comment: Historical context: this answer was useful at the time; the OP thanked the author. Afterwards, the OP asked a follow-up question about how to put comments in `psql` [meta-commands](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) (e.g. `\l` for list databases). At this point in time, only [cjerdonek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20770978/109618) has answered these follow-up questions.

Comment: The weird part is, the follow-up question wasn't even the original author. Someone else just edited the question to ask a different question instead.

Answer (score 9):

It doesn't look like `psql` supports traditional end-of-line `--` comments in its `psql`-specific "slash commands." -- these are called **meta-commands** in the [PostgreSQL psql documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html).

However, if you're okay with the end-of-line comments being displayed on execution, using `\echo` seems to be a valid work-around.  For example:

```
\dt jvcurve_thin.jvcurve_results   \echo my comment #2
```

The "double slash" separator meta-command looks like another possibility (and without the side effect of echoing). Begin a new command with it and immediately start a `--` comment:

```
\dt jvcurve_thin.jvcurve_results   \\ -- my comment #2
```

Finally, switching to the shell and adding a shell comment seems like another possibility:

```
\dt jvcurve_thin.jvcurve_results   \! # my comment #2
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't use two backslashes \\ since these are used to separate commands for `psql`, e.g. `\d table1 \\ \d table2`, and can exhibit behaviour when the supposed comment includes `psql` commands. See description of the option `-c` [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-psql.html).

Comment: Thanks, @valid. How about prepending the text after \\ with `--` then, as in `\\ --` my comment.

Comment: oh yeah. That seems alright. It still introduces some _different_ behaviour. When typing double-dash into psql interactive console that comment command and those directly following are collected and stored into history with the next (comment-breaking) non-comment command - quasi behaving like a multiline comment. Double-backslash combined with double-dash doesn't work in the same way, i.e. the comment is not compiled with the following command(s). Even though I'd consider all of this wanted behaviour I don't find it particularly intuitive. So be aware ;)

Comment: @valid Interesting. I guess in the case of double-slash followed by a double-hyphen comment, it could be argued that it makes sense for an end-of-line comment to be associated only with that line (because it is an end-of-line comment).

Answer (score 5):

From the official documentation: [PostgreSQL Comments](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-COMMENTS).

> A comment is a sequence of characters beginning with double dashes and
>   extending to the end of the line, e.g.:
>
> ```
> -- This is a standard SQL comment
> ```
>
> Alternatively, C-style block comments can be used:
>
> ```
> /* multiline comment  * with nesting: /* nested block comment */  */
> ```
>
> where the comment begins with /* and extends to the matching
>   occurrence of */. These block comments nest, as specified in the SQL
>   standard but unlike C, so that one can comment out larger blocks of
>   code that might contain existing block comments.
>
> A comment is removed from the input stream before further syntax
>   analysis and is effectively replaced by whitespace.

And it has been supported the same way ever since dark ages (version 7.0).

Answer (score -3):

It's Better to select and press Ctrl+Shift+/ to comment multiline in PostgreSQL pgAdmin4